# How to check for duplicate username and/or email in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello guys i have a simple pdo login and register page, and when i test it in localhost, I could register same usernames and emails. How do i check for duplication in registration page, and shows an error if same user/email already exist? This is my register.php

```
<?php
require 'config.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header('location:dashboard.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
    $errMsg = '';

    // Get data from FROM
    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $secretpin = $_POST['secretpin'];

    if($fullname == '')
        $errMsg = 'Enter your fullname!';
    if($username == '')
        $errMsg = 'Enter username!';
    if($address == '')
        $errMsg = 'Enter a valid email!';
    if($password == '')
        $errMsg = 'Enter password!';
    if($secretpin == '')
        $errMsg = 'Enter a sercret pin number!';


    if($errMsg == ''){
        try {
            $stmt = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO pdo (fullname, username, address, password, secretpin) VALUES (:fullname, :username, :address, :password, :secretpin)');
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':fullname' => $fullname,
                ':username' => $username,
                ':address' => $address,
                ':password' => $password,
                ':secretpin' => $secretpin,

                ));
            header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
            exit;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined') {
    $errMsg = 'Registration successfull. Now you can <a href="login.php">login</a>';
}
?>
```

And my other problem is, how to get  the registration date of every person who register and save in the database and echo the date in the profile page. Im just a newbie in php and i get some ideas in other open source php codes. Thanks guys.

P.S dont mind about the security, Im still learning about that :)

Comment: *"And my other problem is"* - That made the question "too broad". You  are expected to try something then post what you had problems with and post errors you may have gotten; given that you're looking out for them.

Comment: You could use SELECT COUNT .... WHERE Email = 'test@y.z' and then check whether the result is  >0 or not

Answer (score 1):

Your security is already slightly enhanced by the fact you are using PDO rather than the deprecated mysql or mysqli.

Checking for duplication is simply a case of an SQL "LIKE" statement query - like so -

SELECT * FROM websiteUsers WHERE userEmail or userLogin LIKE ?

an example of this can actually be found on this link - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

I would not want to undermine your approach, however bear in mind that at the moment your code here:

```
if($fullname == '')
    $errMsg = 'Enter your fullname!';
if($username == '')
    $errMsg = 'Enter username!';
if($address == '')
    $errMsg = 'Enter a valid email!';
if($password == '')
    $errMsg = 'Enter password!';
if($secretpin == '')
    $errMsg = 'Enter a sercret pin number!';
```

will overwrite the $errMsg everytime, so you won't get the full set of errors either, which might or might not be important.

I know you didn't want security pointers as such, but using

```
if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined') {
```

as a way of knowing if someone is registered is not a good idea either, please either use a framework or change your approach, as this one suggests I can access that url without actually filling out your form.